# Google Maps API Deprecation Error in VueJS web app: utc_offset is deprecated as of November 2019 and will be turned off in November 2020

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vuex

I'm currently receiving the following error in my VueJS web application.

> utc_offset is deprecated as of November 2019 and will be turned off in
>   November 2020. Use utc_offset_minutes instead.

As per [Google Maps API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/place_field_js_migration):

> The Places fields opening_hours.open_now and utc_offset are deprecated
>   as of November 20, 2019, and will be turned off on November 20, 2020.
>   These fields are deprecated ONLY in the Places Library, Maps
>   JavaScript API. This guide shows you how to update your code to stop
>   using these fields.

The only problem is, I am definitely **not** using utc_offset anywhere in my Vue application directly. I verified this by doing a global find for the word "utc_offset" in my application. I also don't ever recall accessing that specific property.

**Why am I receiving this deprecation warning if I didn't use that property?**

Below is what my stack trace looks like:

[image]

The following code snippet shows what the `clearAllCardsAndFilters` method does.

```
methods: {
    clearAllCardsAndFilters() {
        this.clearActiveCardListingId();
        this.clearFilterCards();
    },
    clearActiveCardListingId() {
        this.$store.commit('clearActiveCardListingId');
    },
```

The following code snippet shows what the `clearActiveCardListingId` mutation in Vuex does. It simply sets the `activeCardListingId` property in Vuex to `null`.

```
    clearActiveCardListingId(state) {
        state.activeCardListingId = null;
    },
```

Comment: Maybe if you request place details without specifying any `fields` which would return **all** the fields (which you should probably avoid because of billing). Without seeing your code, it's impossible to say anyway so I'll vote to close your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the Google Places API without specifying any fields. This deprecation warning goes away once you specify fields in the following manner. Make sure you avoid specifying "utc_offset" as a field or the message will come back.

```
new google.maps.places.PlacesService(attrContainer).getDetails({
  placeId: '...',
  fields: ['opening_hours','utc_offset_minutes'],
  }, function (place, status) {
    if (status !== 'OK') return; // something went wrong
    const isOpenAtTime = place.opening_hours.isOpen(new Date('December 17, 2020 03:24:00'));
    if (isOpenAtTime) {
        // We know it's open.
    }

    const isOpenNow = place.opening_hours.isOpen();
    if (isOpenNow) {
        // We know it's open.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using VUE2-google-maps, then you can use google map component in following way:

```
<GmapAutocomplete
 @place_changed="setPlace"
 :options="{fields: ['geometry', 'formatted_address', 'address_components']}">
</GmapAutocomplete>
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me without **:options**

```
:fields="['geometry', 'opening_hours', 'business_status']"
```